# C# identifying items within a for loop

Tags: c#

I've created a for loop that will be used to display 8 items per section, but I'm trying to identify certain items within the loop. For instance I want to identify the first two items, then fifth and sixth but can seem to get my identification techniques correct.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){
    var item = Model[i]
    if ((i + 1) % 3 != 0 && (i + 1) % 4 != 0){
        // What i want to display here
    }
    else{
        // Something else I want to display
    }
}
```

This kind of works for the first four items but for the last four items it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does the counter not do that for you. If (i == 0 || i == 1) ? is the first 2 items for example.

Comment: FYI doing modulo by 1 will always return 0 since all integers are divisible by 1.

Comment: Why not simply: `int[] takeIndexes={0,1,3,4}; for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){ if(takeIndexes.Contains(i)){...}else{...} }`

Comment: Isn´t `(i + 1) % 1 == 0` **allways** true?

Comment: Yep, ( i + 1) % 1 == 0 this is always true, ill correct it

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, if `i` is an `int`.

Comment: @juharr Which it is from the OPs code.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that if `Model` has 24 items in you'd want to pick out `1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21` with the `if`, everything else would be in the `else`?

Comment: @Equalsk sorry ive corrected it 1,2,5,6... first 2 items, miss 2, next 2

Comment: OK, so `1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22`?

Comment: @Equalsk, yep that is correct

Comment: I dont know if that's what you want but `Model.Where(v => (v + 1) % 3 != 0 || (v + 1) % 4 != 0)` will return something like `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){
    var item = Model[i]
    int aux = i%4;
    if (aux==0|| aux==1){
        // What i want to display here
    }
    else{
        // Something else I want to display
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (i % 4 < 2)` is a little cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing around with `modulo` a 'cheap' trick is to just have a counter that keeps track of where you are and resets on each loop.

```
// Dummy list to represent whatever 'Model' is
var model = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve" };

// A counter that keeps track of whether we're on 1, 2, 5 or 6
var counter = 1;

// Your loop
for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
{
    // Get the item as you've shown
    var item = model[i];

    // Check whether we want this item or not
    if (counter == 1 || counter == 2 || counter == 5 || counter == 6)
    {
        // Display
        Console.WriteLine("Displayed: " + item);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do whatever else
        Console.WriteLine("Skipped: " + item);
    }

    // Increase the counter
    counter++;

    // Reset the counter if we're into the next batch of 8
    if (counter > 8)
        counter = 1;
}
```

Output:

> Displayed: one
>   Displayed: two
>   Skipped: three
>   Skipped: four
>   Displayed: five
>   Displayed: six
>   Skipped: seven
>   Skipped: eight
>   Displayed: nine
>   Displayed: ten
>   Skipped: eleven
>   Skipped: twelve

I admit it's not very 'fancy' but it works fine and is easy to understand.